# Do While Loop does not recognize scanner input before while loop is tested

Tags: java, loops, input, java.util.scanner, do-while

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switch {


    private static void case1() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter side A");
        String a = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter side B");
        String b = input.next();

        double number1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
        double number2 = Double.parseDouble(b);


        double A2 = number1 * number1;
        double B2 = number2 * number2;

        System.out.println(A2);
        System.out.println(B2);

        double Csq = A2 + B2;

        double C = Math.sqrt(Csq);

        System.out.println("C equals " + C);
        input.close();
    }

    private static void case2() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter side A");
        String a = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter side C");
        String c = input.next();

        double number1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
        double number2 = Double.parseDouble(c);


        double A2 = number1 * number1;
        double C2 = number2 * number2;

        System.out.println(A2);
        System.out.println(C2);

        double b1 = C2 - A2;

        double B = Math.sqrt(b1);

        System.out.println("B equals " + B);
        input.close();
    }

    private static void case3() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter side B");
        String b = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter side C");
        String c = input.next();

        double number1 = Double.parseDouble(b);
        double number2 = Double.parseDouble(c);


        double B2 = number1 * number1;
        double C2 = number2 * number2;

        System.out.println(B2);
        System.out.println(C2);

        double a1 = C2 - B2;

        double A = Math.sqrt(a1);

        System.out.println("A equals " + A);
        input.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cont = "y";

        do {

            try{
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Pythagorean Theorm Program!!");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Choose one of the following:");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("1. A2 + B2 = X");
                System.out.println("2. A2 + X = C2");
                System.out.println("3. X + B2 = C2");

                int choice = input.nextInt();

                switch (choice) {

                    case 1: case1();
                            break;
                    case 2: case2();
                            break;
                    case 3: case3();
                            break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            String more = input.next();
        } while (more.equals(cont));



    }
}
```

I need a user input just before the while loop that way it will know if the program wants to continue.  Problem is that the more inside of the while condition does not see the scanner input a line before.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Don't call `input.close()` in your methods. It will close your input stream.

Comment: It says more is not resolved.  That is my problem, it does not see that more is being created as an input string the line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the String more declaration outside the while loop :

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cont = "y";
        String more = null;


        do {

            try{
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Pythagorean Theorm Program!!");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Choose one of the following:");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("1. A2 + B2 = X");
                System.out.println("2. A2 + X = C2");
                System.out.println("3. X + B2 = C2");

                int choice = input.nextInt();

                switch (choice) {

                    case 1: case1();
                            break;
                    case 2: case2();
                            break;
                    case 3: case3();
                            break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            more = input.next();
        } while (more.equals(cont));



    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `more` is only in scope inside the do while loop. One solution would be to declare more outside the loop and only update its value inside.

Like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cont = "y";
    String more = null;

    do {
        .
        .// code here
        .

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
        more = input.next();
    } while (more.equals(cont));
```

This happens because any variable which is declared inside a do-while construct is only in scope within that same loop, it cannot be accessed outside the loop, or in the loop condition.

Declaring the variable outside the loop and within main gives access to the variable anywhere inside the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is variable scope, you have defined the String more during your do statement and then have the while condition outside of it , to fix it you need to change the scope to local to the main function instead , to do this just add this to your code before the do

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cont = "y";
    String more = null;
    do {
    // rest of code
```

You will also need to get rid of the "String" keyword for defining the datatype of more in your do but that should be it.

Although if you're goal is to repeat the program if they need to use it again why dont you encapsulate the entirety of your main function in the while loop instead with the condition being dependant of the user input at the end of the loop for example

```
boolean more = True;
While(more = True){
    // your current code
    // then check to see if they want to go again, if not , change more to false
}
```

I hope this helps